# SignalR and AngularJS

Tags: .net, angularjs, signalr

I use SignalR for my app, and it works with simple javascript,but now I'm trying to rewrite it with angular-wrapper https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub, but I run into the error while trying to connect to my hub:

```
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()
at Object.signalR.fn.signalR.send (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:789:23)
at Object.hubProxy.fn.hubProxy.invoke (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:2609:24)
at Hub.invoke (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular-signalr-hub.js:30:28)
at Hub.(anonymous function) [as loadRecentPhotos] (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular-signalr-hub.js:49:24)
at Object.PhotoMarkers.load (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/AngApp.js:47:17)
at http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular.js:10836:21
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular.js:12673:28)
at pre (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular.js:19943:15)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular.js:6684:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:47124/Scripts/angular.js:6098:13) <div class="modal-body" ng-init="markers.load()">
```

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('FlickrMaps', ['SignalR'])
.factory('PhotoMarkers', ['$rootScope', 'Hub', function ($rootScope, Hub) {
    var PhotoMarkers = this;

    //Hub setup
    var hub = new Hub('photos', {
        listeners: {
            'addTotalPhotosCount': function (total) {
                PhotoMarkers.totalCount = total;
                $rootScope.$apply();
            },

            'initPhotoMarker': function (photo) {
                var photolocation = new window.google.maps.LatLng(photo.Latitude, photo.Longitude);
                PhotoMarkers.all.push(new window.google.maps.Marker({
                    position: photolocation,
                    title: photo.Title,
                    photoThumb: photo.PhotoThumbScr,
                    photoOriginal: photo.PhotoOriginalScr
                }));
                $rootScope.$apply();
            },

            'photosProcessed': function () {
                PhotoMarkers.processedPhotosCount++;
                $rootScope.$apply();
            },
        },
        methods: ['loadRecentPhotos'],
        errorHandler: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });

    //Variables
    PhotoMarkers.all = [];
    PhotoMarkers.processedPhotosCount = 0;
    PhotoMarkers.totalCount = 0;

    //Methods
    PhotoMarkers.load = function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });
        hub.loadRecentPhotos();
    };

    return PhotoMarkers;
}])
.controller('MapController', ['$scope', 'PhotoMarkers', function ($scope, PhotoMarkers) {
$scope.markers = PhotoMarkers;
}])
```

Does anyone acquainted with that?

Comment: well the error message says to call `start`.  did you try that?

Comment: The idea of this wrapper (angular service) https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub, as I undersand, is to  control hub starting and simplifying declaretion of hub listeners and methods on client side.

Comment: this is not ralated to signalr but why are you using jquery modal, try to use an angularJS directive for doing that http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: well, I'm new in angular and just do first steps. But I'll use that next time, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderSmith are you open for another wrapper solution, I can post a custom wrapper which is more flexible, let me know!

Comment: Do you call load method? can you add view portion of your code?

Comment: shameless plugin, you could check this out: github.com/roylee0704/angular-signalr

Answer (score 3):

You must be running into asynch issues. When you invoke method, the connection is not open yet.

Try fixing your `signalr-hub.js`, I think we should use different promises for stop and start.

```
    Hub.disconnect = function () {
        Hub.stopPromise = Hub.connection.stop();
    };
    Hub.connect = function () {
        Hub.startPromise = Hub.connection.start();
    };
```

And:

```
angular.forEach(options.methods, function (method) {
        Hub[method] = function () {
            var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
            args.unshift(method);
            return Hub.startPromise.then(function(){
                //invoke method only after startPromise is resolved
                 return Hub.invoke.apply(Hub, args);
            }
        };
});
```

Or:

```
angular.forEach(options.methods, function (method) {
        Hub[method] = function () {
            var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
            args.unshift(method);

            var def = $q.def();
            Hub.startPromise.then(function(){
                    //invoke method only after startPromise is resolved
                  Hub.invoke.apply(Hub, args).done(function(){
                         def.resolve();
                  });
            }

            return def.promise;
        };
 });
```

Don't forget to inject `$q` into your Hub. This returns an angular promise instead of a jQuery promise. Therefore, angular is aware of the event, we don't need to use `$rootScope.$apply()` in your callback.

And:

```
//Adding additional property of promise allows to access it in rest of the application.
   Hub.startPromise = Hub.connection.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a basic working example of this on Github.
Hope it helps. While it does use authentication, if this is not important for you.
You can simply remove the authentication part.

https://github.com/louislewis2/AngularJSAuthentication

Regards

Louis

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of the SignalR-Hub project, the connection should be started when creating a new hub. Have you checked your browser console for possible connection errors?

The library also provides access to the `start()` promise. Attach yourself to this promise to check wether the hub has successfully ben connected to your server. Example:

```
hub.promise
    .done(function(){ console.log('connection established'); })
    .fail(function(){ console.log('connection error'); });
```

the promise object is the access to the promise of the signalR start method.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed [[here]](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub/issues/8)

vmlf01's comment is:

The hub created has a ".promise" property that corresponds to the return value from ".start()". I initialize my connection using a promise and resolving it in the done() callback when the connection is established, like so:

```
    function initialize() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        foldersHubConnection = new Hub('Folders', {
            listeners: folderHubListeners(),
            methods: folderServerCalls(),
            rootPath: config.eventsServerEndpoint
        });

        foldersHubConnection.promise.done(function () {
            deferred.resolve(foldersHubClient);
        });

        foldersHubConnection.promise.fail(function (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error("Error connecting to Events Server: " + error));
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: This is just the same problem as I pointed out in my answer. Just the solutions differ.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you install and reference jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js file

Answer (score 0):

What helped me when wrapping SignalR for AngularJS use was this:

** **Convert all SignalR (jQuery) promises to Angular $q promises.** **

The benefits:

1. All callers have a consistent promise interface (e.g. `finally()` rather than `always()`)
2. Promise is rejected on error (no need for `try`...`catch`), e.g. if connection is not started, as per your question
3. Angular's `$digest` cycle is fired

With that in mind, you could change your `Hub.invoke` method to this:

```
Hub.invoke = function(method, args) {
    try {
       var jQueryPromise = Hub.proxy.invoke.apply(Hub.proxy, arguments);

        return $q.when(jQueryPromise);    // <- return as $q promise

    } catch(e) {
        return $q.reject(e);              // <- exception to $q.reject
    }
```

and `Hub.connect` to

```
Hub.connect = function (queryParams) {
    ...
    return $q.when(Hub.connection.start(startOptions));  // <- return $q promise
};
```